# Searching key of multidimensional array by the value of associated array of that key

Tags: php, arrays, search

```
Array
(
[Roofing] => Array
    (
        [0] => Roofing Contractors
        [1] => Commercial Roofing
        [2] => Contractor Metal Roofing
    )
```

How can i get "Roofing" by "Roofing Contractors" value by seacrhing algorith in php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$search = 'Roofing';
foreach($array as $item) {
    if (strpos($item, $search) !== 0) {
        // entry found
    }
}
```

But there is probably a faster way with pregmatch